# What java 1.7 version is compatible/needed for TLS 1.2

Tags: java, tls1.2

I am trying to upgrade to using TLS 1.2 while keeping java version within Java 1.7. I cannot move up to Java 1.8.

We tried upgrading with 1.8 but the application blew up.

Comment: Given that Java 7 [went out of *extended* support in July 2022](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/java-se-7-end-of-extended-support-in-july-2022) I would strongly encourage you to put the effort into fixing the application to work with in-support versions rather than spending that effort trying to use a very old version of Java.

Comment: Let's put it more strongly: if you still need to be running this code in 1-2 months, then I **strongly** urge you to schedule a project to upgrade the system to at least run on Java 17 (the current TLS support). For bonus points call the project "RemoveTheDot" (1.7 -> 17).

Answer (score 2):

To anyone unfortunate enough to find this post, current versions of the [Azul Zulu 7 OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/) seem to support setting the `jdk.tls.client.protocols` system property to `TLSv1.2` like is supported in 7u95 for Oracle Business customers.

Comment: Thank you very much! One note for others with similar problem. Choose JDK on zulu site, as JRE will show only versions before u80

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without code (`jdk.tls.client.protocols`) that was added in [7u95](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/7u95-relnotes.html). I strongly agree with the comment above though - it is really high time to update to a more recent version.

Comment: For 7u95, I believe that is only available with extended oracle support.

Comment: That is correct. The alternative (except for upgrading) is to use code. I'm not sure what level of support the last public release had, but it did not support the command line option.